# Biometric sign in with Expo React Native and token

Tags: react-native, expo, biometrics

I have a React Native with expo. Sign in is done with username and password, where I send this data to an API that returns a token that I save in Expo secure store and then I use this token in every request.

I want to implement Biometrics with Expo local authentication https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/local-authentication/

but I'm confuse about how to deal with the api.

Do I have to change the API? How do I send the username and password when I sign in with biometrics?